# Create a Contact Group in Outlook 2013 from a selected group of emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Outlook 2013, I'd like to be able to create a Contact Group from the senders of a selected group of emails.

For example, from the screenshot below, you can see I have selected 7 emails. I would like to be able to generate a Contact Group with the senders of the selected emails in it.

[image: Screenshot of list of selected emails]

Is there either a native way or plugin that will allow me to accomplish this? Or, while not as desirable, is their any way to add these senders to my Address Book en masse so I can more easily generate the Contact Group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **free** [Save Addresses from Messages to Contact Group](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesEmailSaveGroup/) add-in that does exactly what you described. It can be run from within selection's context menu or just from Outlook ribbon.